# Checking for GeoIP in nGinx does not work

Tags: http, security, nginx, debian, geoip

I have a list of countries that I want to restrict access to the web application. For example, users from Russia should be prohibited from visiting my web application. I downloaded the database of countries and created a separate file with a map. Then I registered the configs in `nginx.conf`, but the access was not blocked. What could be the problem?

**Base:**

*https://mirrors-cdn.liferay.com/geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoIP.dat.gz*

The path to this file is: `/etc/nginx/geoip/GeoIP.dat`

**New include file with map block.map.include:**

The path to this file is: `/etc/nginx/block.map.include`

```java
geoip_country /etc/nginx/geoip/GeoIP.dat;  
map $geoip_country_code $allowed_country {  
        default yes;
        RU no;
        ...//and more contries
}
```

**In `nginx.conf` I add include with modules:**

```
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*;
```

**and then in `http{}` add:**

```
#GeoIP
include /etc/nginx/block.map.include;
```

**In all `server{}` groups I add:**

```
if ($allowed_country = no) {
    return 403;
}
```

**My complete `nginx.conf`**

```java
user root;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*;
worker_processes     auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 20960;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept        on;
    use                 epoll;
    epoll_events        512;
}

http {

    #GeoIP
    include /etc/nginx/block.map.include;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log   combined;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/warn.log     warn;

    server_tokens off;

    upstream thumbor {
        server localhost:8888;
    }

    upstream solr {
        server localhost:8983;
    }

    upstream minio {
        server localhost:9000;
    }

    upstream activemq {
        server localhost:8161;
    }

    upstream wildfly {
        ip_hash;
        server localhost:8008;
        server localhost:8018;
    }

    server {
        if ($allowed_country = no) {
            return 403;
        }
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/__****.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private.key;
        ssl_verify_client       off;
        root                    /var/www/special/not/exist/html;
        server_name             ****.ru;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }

    server {
        if ($allowed_country = no) {
            return 403;
        }
        listen 80;
        server_name ****.ru;
        rewrite ^ https://****.ru$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    server {
        if ($allowed_country = no) {
            return 403;
        }
        listen                      443 ssl;
        server_name                 ****.ru;
        ssl_certificate             /etc/ssl/__****.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key         /etc/ssl/private.key;
        ssl_protocols               TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_ciphers                 HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

        client_body_buffer_size         8k;
        client_max_body_size            20m;
        client_body_in_single_buffer    on;
        client_header_buffer_size       1m;
        large_client_header_buffers 4   8k;

        location /****/thumbor/ {
            proxy_pass http://thumbor/;
        }

        location /solr {
            proxy_pass http://solr;
        }

        location /minio {
            proxy_pass http://minio;
        }

        location /activemq {
            proxy_pass http://activemq;
        }


        location / {
            proxy_pass http://wildfly/;

            proxy_buffer_size 16k;
            proxy_buffers 16 16k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
            proxy_read_timeout 180s;

            proxy_set_header   Host              $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST|DELETE|PUT)$ ) {
                return 405;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Server is on `DEBIAN`. No warnings and errors in `nGinx`.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can turn on debugging mode as mentioned there http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html